# Combining Different regular expression parts with a variable piece

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

Hello Stack Community!

I have come across an issue when trying to create a trigger in GTM (Google Tag Manager), where I need google to fire the tag when certain parameters are met within a URL string.

Here is the string of URL would look like, and we need to write a regex to trigger the tag to fire based on that.

There are three parts to this: 
Sample url:

```
espn.com/search_[variable]-ThankyouPage
```

1. Search
2. Variable - this is where a wildcard can be used I imagine.
3. Thank you page

So when I tried it, I got as far as : `'search'|.()\|'TY'` . But that doesn't seem to work.

What would be the best method to write a regex where we combine those three parameters to apply in Google Tag Manager?

Thank you!

Comment: `.*` is how you match anything in a regular expression. Is that all you need to know?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I am a noob in writing regex, so was wondering if you can provide an example on how to write the expression?

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading the tutorial at regular-expression.info.

Comment: This is about as simple as regular expressions get, even a noob should be able to do it.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Constructive help, really great stuff.

Comment: Instead of snarky comments that provide no utility to anything or anyone, you could be supportive in helping someone interested in solving a problem.

Comment: What happened to "really great stuff"?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: So when I tried it, I got as far as : 
'search'|.()\|'TY' .

But that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is:

```
espn\.search/search_(.*)-ThankYouPage
```

You don't need `|`, that's for specifying alternative strings to match. To match consecutive strings, you simply concatenate them.

And there's no `'` in the URL, so that shouldn't be in the regular expression at all.

`()` creates a capture group, you put it *around* the variable part that you want to extract.

You need `*` after `.` to indicate that any number of characters are allowed there. `.` matches just a single character.